# String char-set in Java and Oracle DB

Tags: java, string, oracle, jakarta-ee, varchar2

Hi i am using Oracle DB to store string on Varchar2 column,

with using eclipselink my code is here,

```
pdescription = new String(this.description.getBytes("ISO-8859-9"));
```

sometimes its ok but, somtimes it only question marks, like that
 it is taken "door" or "????"

I have column that is also string there is problem with that, their types are same both varchar2

Comment: What do you expect that code to achieve? You're converting a string into ISO-8859-9, and then converting it *back* to a string using the platform default encoding. That seems like a very bad idea to me.

Comment: Actually, string which have different char like "Şöşışğ" stored in db, without ISO-8859-9 different chars are appearing like "ÃÂ±ÃÂÃÂ±ÃÂ", so when using ISO-8859-9 it is ok but sometimes it is appearing "??????"

Comment: I'm sorry, I really didn't follow that - you should explain in more detail *exactly* what you mean in your question.

Comment: @JonSkeet It sounds like the wrong character set is either being stored in (or retrieved from) the database... and that this is an XY problem.